# Merging two DataFrames matching rows/columns

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, merge

Given two dataframes of two different dimensions, how could I go about merging one on top of the other keeping the dimensions of the larger df and inserting the data from the smaller where needed.

```
x = matrix(data = 1:4, nrow = 20, ncol = 22)

y = matrix(data = NA, nrow = 26, ncol = 26)
```

something such as this where Y is a full blank matrix and X is a matrix of actual data points. How could I go about merging them such that the data from X is overlayed onto the matrix of Y

I've tried something like

```
Z<- merge(Y, X, by = "Country", all.x= TRUE)
```

but what ends up happening is I get a DF doubled in size of columns with the data appended onto the end of the Y DF.

I have also attempted this

```
    library(dplyr)
    Z<- merge(Y, X, by = "Country", all.x = T)
      Z%>% 
        mutate(Afghanistan = ifelse(is.na(Afghanistan.x), Afghanistan.x, Afghanistan.y)) %>% 
           select(-Afghanistan.y, -Afghanistan.x)
```

For reference, my table's rows/column names are countries. This method works however it only replaces 1 column at a time, is a loop possible to properly input all data for all columns?

Comment: `merge` is for combining two `data.frame`s based on one or more common columns. When you say *"one on top of the other"*, that to me sounds like `rbind` (or `dplyr::bind_rows`, though again this one is only for frames). Regardless, your `x` and `y` are matrices (with no column names), then you try to `merge` two objects `X` and `Y` on a column names `"Country"`, so I'm not really sure what we should be working with here.

Comment: my examples x and y are matrices I should have created dataframes instead, that is my mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subset `y` with dimensions of `x` and assign -

```
y[1:nrow(x), 1:ncol(x)] <- x
y
```

Answer (score 0):

Along the lines of the answer given by @ronak-shah, if your `y` dataframe has all the row and column names of `x` (plus some more which are not part of `x`), then you can simply subset by the row and column names to fit `x` within `y`.

Creating the example matrices:

```
x <- as.data.frame(matrix(data = 1:3, nrow = 5, ncol = 6))
y <- as.data.frame(matrix(data = NA, nrow = 10, ncol = 10))
```

Renaming some of the rows and columns to create our example:

```
row.names(x)=c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
colnames(x)=c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V5", "V6", "V8")
row.names(y)=c("1",  "2",  "a",  "b",  "5",  "c",  "7",  "d",  "9",  "e")
```

Now, fitting `x` within `y`:

```
y[row.names(x), colnames(x)] <- x
```

This will fill in the elements in `y` that match the row and column names in `x`, but leave the others untouched.